# How to use the new Wordpress 4.4 JSON API?

Tags: json

Until today I have used the plugin "WP REST API (WP API)". Now I want to use the built-in API but can't find any documentation on it.
Any idea?

Comment: For sure I have tried this. But here http://v2.wp-api.org/ it says download the plugin. I want to use the core api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WP REST API is being developed for WordPress as a **Feature Plugin**.

A **Feature Plugin** is:

> ... the way for features to be developed for inclusion in WordPress core.
>   This model allows a feature to be built, tested, refined, and polished
>   before it is considered as a merge candidate

*source*: https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/about/release-cycle/features-as-plugins/

Therefore, the WP REST API *is* the new WordPress built-in API and the [documentation for the WP REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/) plugin is also the documentation for the built-in WP API. However, **not all features from the plugin have been merged into core WordPress yet**.

For WordPress 4.4, the best documentation of how to use what is **currently built-in** into WordPress is documented in this post on the [Make WordPress](https://make.wordpress.org/core) blog:

> **REST API: Welcome the Infrastructure to Core** https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/10/28/rest-api-welcome-the-infrastructure-to-core/

However, because the merge into WordPress core will be an on-going, phased process, the best way to keep up with changes per release is to track these sources:

- Make WordPress 'rest-api' tag: 
  https://make.wordpress.org/core/tag/rest-api/
- Github: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/milestones

Comment: To get all pages I use this URI with the plugin enabled: /wp-json/pages but the same URI without the plugin won't work. Does this feature work on Wp 4.4?

Comment: @KlevisMiho Unfortunately, URL endpoints aren't yet a part of core.  "_In 4.4, the infrastructure is now available as part of core, while the endpoints continue to only be available in the plugin_" (from the post linked to above)

Answer (score 0):

The REST API infrastructure was added to WordPress core in 4.4 and the endpoints are being added in 4.5 I believe.

tl;dr - half of it is in WordPress so you still need the plugin to add the endpoints until 4.5 is released.